Store Token from Microsoft.Graph results in error invalid_client AADSTS650057
I authenticate against an App to use Microsoft.Graph in a WPF Desktop app. For thsi I use InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions, what works greate until I try to serialise the Token for the next start of the application.
I init the InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
private readonly string[] _scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
private const string AUTH_RECORD_PATH = "./tokencache.bin";

_options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
{
    TenantId = tenantId,
    ClientId = clientId,
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/secret"),
    TokenCachePersistenceOptions = new TokenCachePersistenceOptions
    {
        Name = "OneDriveService",
        UnsafeAllowUnencryptedStorage = true
    }
};

And then try to store the Toke what causes an error:
 AuthenticationRecord authRecord = await interactiveCredential.AuthenticateAsync();

 using (var authRecordStream = new FileStream(AUTH_RECORD_PATH, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
 {
     await authRecord.SerializeAsync(authRecordStream);
 }

But then I got in the Browser the error: Error details: error invalid_client error_description: AADSTS650057: Invalid resource. The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client's application registration.
I tryed to change the scope and the API Permissions in entry, currently I have File.ReadWrite.All, Application.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All, AuthenticationContext.Read.All, offline_access, openid, profile, User.read.
But that did not help.

Which API are you trying to access?

I use Graph to up and download files to oneDrive

Initially I got the same error:


The error "AADSTS650057: Invalid resource. The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client's application registration" usually occurs if the authentication request scope do not match the API permissions granted to the application.
In your scenario to resolve the error, force the auth request to use Microsoft Graph API scope by adding var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(_scopes); in the code like below:
public class GraphAuth
{
    private static readonly string[] _scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    private const string AUTH_RECORD_PATH = "./tokencache.bin";

    public static async Task AuthenticateAndStoreTokenAsync(string tenantId, string clientId)
    {
        var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
        {
            TenantId = tenantId,
            ClientId = clientId,
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
            RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/secret"),
            TokenCachePersistenceOptions = new TokenCachePersistenceOptions
            {
                Name = "OneDriveService",
                UnsafeAllowUnencryptedStorage = true 
            }
        };

        var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

        // Create a TokenRequestContext with the specified Microsoft Graph scope
        var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(_scopes);
        var accessToken = await interactiveCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext);

        Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {accessToken.Token}");

        using (var tokenCacheStream = new FileStream(AUTH_RECORD_PATH, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            byte[] tokenBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(accessToken.Token);
            await tokenCacheStream.WriteAsync(tokenBytes, 0, tokenBytes.Length);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Authentication successful and token stored.");
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string tenantId = "TenantID";  
        string clientId = "ClientID";  

        Task.Run(() => AuthenticateAndStoreTokenAsync(tenantId, clientId)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}


The token is stored successfully:

UPDATE:
To reuse the stored token, you do not need to manually load or set the AuthenticationRecord.

Instead, use the TokenCachePersistenceOptions to manage tokens automatically. The InteractiveBrowserCredential takes care of caching and refreshing tokens, ensuring smooth token reuse across sessions.
The InteractiveBrowserCredential manages the token cache automatically.
The InteractiveBrowserCredential does not allow you to directly load or set the access token or an AuthenticationRecord, but it can leverage a token cache to store and retrieve tokens.

Try the below code:
public class GraphAuth
{
    private static readonly string[] _scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    private const string AUTH_RECORD_PATH = "./tokencache.bin";

    // Function to authenticate and store the token
    public static async Task AuthenticateAndStoreTokenAsync(string tenantId, string clientId)
    {
        var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
        {
            TenantId = tenantId,
            ClientId = clientId,
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
            RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/secret"),
            TokenCachePersistenceOptions = new TokenCachePersistenceOptions
            {
                Name = "OneDriveService",
                UnsafeAllowUnencryptedStorage = true
            }
        };

        var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

        var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(_scopes);
        var accessToken = await interactiveCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext);

        Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {accessToken.Token}");

        // Save the token to a file (optional, for manual inspection or storage)
        using (var tokenCacheStream = new FileStream(AUTH_RECORD_PATH, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            byte[] tokenBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(accessToken.Token);
            await tokenCacheStream.WriteAsync(tokenBytes, 0, tokenBytes.Length);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Authentication successful and token stored.");
    }

    // Function to authenticate using an existing cached token
    public static async Task AuthenticateWithStoredTokenAsync(string tenantId, string clientId)
    {
        var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
        {
            TenantId = tenantId,
            ClientId = clientId,
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
            RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/secret"),
            TokenCachePersistenceOptions = new TokenCachePersistenceOptions
            {
                Name = "OneDriveService",
                UnsafeAllowUnencryptedStorage = true
            }
        };

        var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

        // Check if the token is already cached
        var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(_scopes);
        var accessToken = await interactiveCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext);

        Console.WriteLine($"Reused Access Token: {accessToken.Token}");
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string tenantId = "TenantID";  
        string clientId = "ClientID";  
        // Run token storage and reuse in a sequential flow
        Task.Run(async () => 
        {
            await AuthenticateAndStoreTokenAsync(tenantId, clientId);
            await AuthenticateWithStoredTokenAsync(tenantId, clientId);
        }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}


Also you can make use of acquiretokensilent it first attempt a silent token request by using the acquireTokenSilent method. When this method is called, the library first checks the cache in browser storage to see if a non-expired access token exists and returns it. If no access token is found or the access token found has expired, it attempts to use its refresh token to get a fresh access token


Thanks a lot, but how do I reuse the Stored Token? In my code I tryed to load it from the file and set it as ````InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions.AuthenticationRecord``` but now I have a Access Token and not finding a way to reuse it.

I asked how to get a ``AuthenticationRecordand your showed how to get a AccessToken``` that may ok if it help me to solve my problem, but it does not so I don't see why this should be a diffrent question.

The InteractiveBrowserCredential does not allow you to manually load a Token or AuthenticationRecord directly for re-use

Microsoft lists it here as supported: TokenCache

In your scenario, you are storing an access token manually to reuse it later. However, the InteractiveBrowserCredential doesn't allow for directly loading or setting an AuthenticationRecord or an access token manually. Instead, you should use the TokenCache mechanism to store and retrieve tokens, which will automatically handle the token refresh and management for you.

To reuse the stored access token or the token cache, you should use the TokenCache functionality and make use of a PersistentTokenCache that can load tokens from a file

@DanielW. Please check the updated answer let me know if its useful:)

Any update on the issue?

It not really does what I need. Is saw with serialize the there should be a possibility to "Silently authenticate a user" so he not have to reenter the credentials or being forwarded to the browser anytime he restarts the application. That was how I understand silently-authenticate-a-user-with-authenticationrecord-and-tokencachepersistenceoptions
But may be I'm wrong, a lot of thanks for your help.

Yeah you can make use of acquiretokensilently too

@DanielW. Updated the answer

Please consider accepting the answer by clicking the ✅ beside it and upvote it, if it's helpful
